# Android: Add items to spinner with a loop

Tags: android, xml, spinner

I'm trying to add items to a spinner with a loop, but can't get it to work. The XML reader part works, I just need to fill the spinner. I tried to adapt that code snippet that's being copypasted around here (the one with the simple_spinner_item) but without success.

Workflow:

```
1) There's an empty spinner 
2) Delete all items in the spinner (in case I add items to it again) 
3) Parse XML 
4) Add the items from the XML to the spinner
```

---

LAYOUT:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/SPI_Test"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/test_prompt" />
```

VIEW:

```
//SPINNER
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SPI_Test);


//CLEAR OUT SPINNER SOMEHOW

//XML READER BOTTOM PART
 for (int j = 0; j < childNodes.getLength()-1; j++) {
    Node item = childNodes.item(j);
//SOMEHOW_ADD_TO_SPINNER=item.getTextContent();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the adapter backing the spinner. Something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then in your for loop

```
stringArrayList.add(item.getTextContent());
```

then swap the adapter for the spinner

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stringArrayList);
mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Do you know why the spinner looks different compared to adding values manually through the strings.xml? When I use the manual method, the list items are always large, have a green radio button next to them and the list is scrollable. Using this method, the text is smaller, there's always a blank entry inbetween them and there are no radio buttons.

Comment: No problem, you need to change the resource id to change the look of the spinner. Play around with the android.R.layout.<layouts> or try this other method mySpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item) and so on. I can't remember exactly but one of these methods should help you.

Comment: Hmm, that worked too, but turned my "normal" spinner button into a big one that looks like an item from the spinner list that pops up. Guess I'll leave it like it is!